# How to print a collection of characters next to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code where given an integer n, I want to print out all integers in the interval [1→n] that divide n, separated with spaces. I wrote this code:

```
n = int(input('Enter number:'))

for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (n%i==0):
        print (i)
```

I get this as the answer:

```
Enter number:8 

1

2

4

8
```

But I want my answer next to each other, separated using spaces (so: `1 2 4 8`). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
print(i)
```

You should put:

```
print(i, end=" ")
```

This will change the end of line string from "\n" to " ". This will give you the desired output.

---

Another method would be to build a list of results and print it out at the end:

```
n = int(input('Enter number:'))
final_results = list()

for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (n%i==0):
        final_results.append(str(i))

print(" ".join(final_results))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(i),
```

(with the comma) Should do the job.

Comment: Since this is Python 3 it should be `print(i),`

Comment: @AmarNabhani Didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest accumulating all intermediate results, and only when the computation is done, print it.

```
n = int(input('Enter number:'))
dividers = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if (n%i==0):
        dividers.append(i)
print(dividers)
```

If you want to print them with nice comma separation, you can do something like this:

```
print(', '.join(str(divider) for divider in dividers))
```

**Benefits**

First, this reduces the number of calls to wherever you are printing to (by default, this is [stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout))

Second, the code becomes more readable and easier to adjust and expand later-on (for example, if you later decide that you want to pass those dividers onto another function)

Edit: adjusted the join operation per ritlew's comment

Comment: The `', '.join(dividers)` will not work if it is a list of integers.